# override actionPerformed on JMenu

Tags: java, swing, menu

I am trying to make a pop up window appear when the user clicks on the About menu. 
Is that possible to do in Java? I have seen that clicking on a menu does not invoke actionPerformed. After a bit of searching i found that i should try to use this:

`new AbstractAction("Do XY")`

but NetBeans tells me that an identifier is expected. Is there any other way to do this, or does Java not allow buttons directly on the Menu bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can do this in Java. You could simply add a `MenuListener` to your menu.

Here is an example of such thing (it also implements the traditional "About" menu item):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.MenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MenuListener;

public class TestAboutMenu {

    protected void initUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
        help.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
                showAboutDialog(frame);
            }

            @Override
            public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("About") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                showAboutDialog(frame);
            }
        });
        help.add(about);
        bar.add(help);
        frame.setJMenuBar(bar);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void showAboutDialog(final JFrame frame) {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame);
        dialog.add(new JLabel("About this program"));
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestAboutMenu().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it you would propably need to write your own Menu bar class. But you could do such trick: Write mouse listener with mouseClicked() method. If you place your menu bar on top then you know it's bounds are: 0, windowWidth(), ~20 (menu bar height), windowWidth(). And then you check if position of mouse is in this rectangle. If yes - you show pop-up window. It's just on the spot idea so let me know if it works for you.

Comment: is there no way to override the Menu functionality for this object only?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any. You could experiment on your own but I think that solution with detecting mouse's click position is the easiest way to achieve your target.